# Update NULL values in column with known values SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, where-clause, sql-null

If I have the following table

| name | nationality |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | french |
| BBB | english |
| CCC | spanish |
| DDD | dutch |
| BBB | `NULL` |
| AAA | `NULL` |

How do I update the `NULL` values with `'english'` and `'french'` respectively

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```sql
UPDATE
    t1
SET
    t1.nationality = known.Nationality
FROM
    t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT name, max(nationality) FROM t1
    ) AS known
        ON t1.name = known.name
```

*Edit*

In the end there are more cases of NULL values for other names

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the purpose of `SELECT name, max(nationality) FROM t1` ?

Comment: Don't you just need `UPDATE t1 SET nationality = CASE name WHEN 'BBB' THEN 'english' WHEN 'AAA' THEN 'french' ELSE nationality END WHERE t1.nationality IS NULL AND name IN ( 'AAA', 'BBB' )` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct [`UPDATE...FROM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) syntax for SQLite 3.33.0+:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET nationality = t2.nationality
FROM (SELECT name, MAX(nationality) nationality FROM tablename GROUP BY name) AS t2
WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND t1.nationality IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=88ed4eda5cacc84858abb7b7ddcbc751).

For previous versions use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE tablename AS t1
SET nationality = (SELECT MAX(t2.nationality) FROM tablename t2 WHERE t2.name = t1.name)
WHERE t1.nationality IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=951e3175d6794cba60aee5823b4e87bf).

Answer (score 0):

Just call UPDATE:

```
UPDATE t1 SET nationality = 'english' WHERE nationality IS NULL AND name = 'AAA';
UPDATE t1 SET nationality = 'french' WHERE nationality IS NULL AND name = 'BBB';
```